# JavaScript: regex to replace foo( to foo (

Tags: javascript, regex

In strings, I try to make a `space` before `(`.

For instance,

`foo(` should be replaced to `foo (`.

In JavaScript,

```
\S\(/g
```

I confirm this regex to match **fo`o(`**, but not sure how to make this replaced to **fo`o (`**

I know this should be done by `$1` variables, but could you show me that way. Thank you.

Comment: Use two capture groups to separate `\S` and `\(`.

Comment: Thanks.Oh sure, but I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = "foo()";
var withSpaces = s.replace(/(\S)\(/g, '$1 (');
```

The only place this will run into trouble is if the parenthesis appears at the beginning of the string, where `\S` will not match.  In that case, you could do this:

```
var withSpaces = s.replace(/(\S|^)\(/g, '$1 (');
```

Comment: Thank you, I cheked answer of yours.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
var str = "foo(hello)";

str = str.replace(/(?=\S\()(\S)/g, "$1 ");
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/tD9mV9

Comment: JavaScript only supports lookaheads, not lookbehinds.  So in your example, using `(?=` does nothing (JavaScript simply interprets this as a regular group).  If you want proof, try your example against the string `'()'`; it will not insert the space (it would if JS supported lookbehinds).

Comment: @EthanBrown, `(?=` IS a lookahead..!  not lookbehind.  My link is a working javascript example.  If you look at the example, "javascript" is the selected engine.

Comment: And no, my regex also works with `'()'`. It put's the space before the `(`.  Just look at my example and test it.  you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

This works -

```
var str = "foo()";
str.replace(/(\S)(\()/, "$1 $2");
//OUTPUT - foo ()
```

Comment: No need for the extra grouip (`$2`) since you're matching a literal.

Comment: Then replacing $2 with "(" would be the solution right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var string =  "foo()";
var foo = string.replace("\(", " (");
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'foo()  abc()';
var regex = /(\S)\(/g;
str = str.replace(regex,"$1 (");//foo ()  abc ()
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(regex,"$1 (");//not duplicate space
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` + `join` alternative :

```
'foo   ()'.split(/ *\(/).join(' (')
```